# Python : 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I have this function, trying to loop over a range of length list to get the ASCII letters:

```
def query_execute (self,query, range):

    list_titles = []
    list_colunmns_letters = []
    cursor.execute(query, range)
    description = cursor.description
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    number_columns = len(description)

    for word in description:
        list_titles.append(word[0])

    for m in range (0,number_columns):
        list_colunmns_letters.append(string.ascii_uppercase[m])

    return row,list_titles,list_colunmns_letters
```

It gives me an Error :

> for m in range (0,number_columns):
>   TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Since the `number_columns` variable is an integer, I don't get why this error happens, I'm not calling a list.

Comment: You replaced the `range` built-in with a list, by using `range` as an argument to the function.

Comment: actually, I'm calling  this function with an other range  : for i in range (0,5):
    row = sql_queries.query_execute(sql_queries.query_test,[i])[0]( )

Comment: So? You don't need to name the list you pass in (with `[i]`) `range`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `range` as a *local* name by making it an argument to your function:

```
def query_execute (self,query, range):
#                              ^^^^^
```

You can't then use the global built-in name as well. Rename the argument to something else; I used `params` instead:

```
def query_execute (self, query, params):
    list_titles = []
    list_colunmns_letters = []
    cursor.execute(query, range)
    description = cursor.description
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    number_columns = len(description)

    for word in description:
        list_titles.append(word[0])

    for m in range(0, number_columns):
        list_colunmns_letters.append(string.ascii_uppercase[m])

    return row, list_titles, list_colunmns_letters
```